# Network request failed when uploading an image to firebase storage using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, expo, firebase-storage

I've been trying to upload images to firebase storage but I keep getting the error:

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

What am I doing wrong?
This is the code.

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    setUploading(true)
    const response = await fetch(image.uri)
    const blob = response.blob()
    const filename = image.uri.substring(image.uri.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
    var ref = storage.ref().child(filename).put(blob)
    try {
        await ref;
        setUploading(false)
        Alert.alert('Photo uploaded!');
        setImage(null);
      } catch (e){
          console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

I don't understand how the firebase storage works. Can you explain it to me?